# Firebase - where to see a nice graph (pie) for user property?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

My app is using 4 different fonts (condensed, normal, bold and thin) and I want to know how many users are using which one. This is my code:

```
FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(activity);
analytics.setUserProperty(PROPERTY_FONT_TYPE, "" + getFontType());
```

I also added this PROPERTY_FONT_TYPE in my firebase console in the part Analytics -> Custom definitions.

How (and where) can I see a graph/pie how many users are using which font?

Firebase console seems to be extremely un-intuitive.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done - but in the Google Analytics console not the Firebase Console. Every Firebase Analytics project (now) has a corresponding Google Analytics 4 property, where a "free-form" exploration can be used to view a pie chart.

**Step 1**

[image: Firebase Console with 'View more in Google Analytics' highlighted]

Press the 'View more in Google Analytics button' in the analytics dashboard of the Firebase console.

**Step 2**

[image: The 'Explore' button highlighted in the Google Analytics interface]

Navigate to the "explore" page in Google Analytics.

**Step 3**

[image: The 'explorations' page in Google Analytics with the create 'free-form' exploration highlighted.]

Create a new 'free-form' exploration.

**Step 4**

[image: The 'doughnut-chart' button in the edit 'free-form' exploration menu]

Change the visualisation to a 'doughnut chart'.

**Step 5**

[image: The remove 'town/city' breakdown and add new dimension buttons highlighted in the edit 'free-form' exploration interface]

Remove the default dimension and then add the new dimension that you are interested in (in this case "PROPERTY_FONT_TYPE"). Drag this to under 'breakdowns' (where the default 'Town/city' dimension was).

**Step 6**

[image: The resulting pie chart]

You can now view a pie chart of your custom user property.

The 'exploration' is automatically saved so you can come back to it later.

Comment: yes you are correct, I figured it out after 2 days of desperate googling and reading like 50 stackoverflow threads...Anyway I marked your reply as answer, it might help somebody in the future :) Google is TERRIBLE at writing documentation - something as important as this should be mentioned in docs...They just can not write a proper documentation, always tons of missing info EVERYWHERE and it is infuriating.